# Spider stuck at listening step

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, listener

I have a scrapy spider that used to work very well but now it seems to be stuck at the listening step:

```
    (scr_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Learning\DataScience\nosetime_scraper\nosetime_scraper\spiders>scrapy crawl sephora
    2020-12-01 16:13:52 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.4.0 started (bot: nosetime_scraper)
    2020-12-01 16:13:52 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.6.1.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 1.22.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.6.7 (v3.6.7
    :6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 13:35:33) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020), cryptography 3.2.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.19041-S
    P0
    2020-12-01 16:13:52 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
    2020-12-01 16:13:52 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
    {'BOT_NAME': 'nosetime_scraper',
     'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
     'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 7,
     'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'nosetime_scraper.spiders',
     'SPIDER_MODULES': ['nosetime_scraper.spiders'],
     'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) '
                   'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 '
                   'Safari/537.36'}
    2020-12-01 16:13:52 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: d2a5851048743566
    2020-12-01 16:13:52 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
    ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
     'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
     'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
    2020-12-01 16:13:53 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
    ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
    2020-12-01 16:13:53 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
    ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
     'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
     'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
     'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
     'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
    2020-12-01 16:13:53 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
    []
    2020-12-01 16:13:53 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
    2020-12-01 16:13:53 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
    2020-12-01 16:13:53 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
    2020-12-01 16:14:53 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
    2020-12-01 16:15:53 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
    2020-12-01 16:15:53 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
    2020-12-01 16:16:53 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
    2020-12-01 16:16:53 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/> (failed 1 times): User timeout caused connect
    ion failure: Getting https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/ took longer than 180.0 seconds..
```

I don't understand ... the spider is quite simle, and the others seem to work ...

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
import json
import requests
import re

class SephoraSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'sephora'
    allowed_domains = ['sephora.fr']
    start_urls = ['https://www.sephora.fr/marques-de-a-a-z/']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log("parse: I just visited: " + response.url)
        urls = response.css('a.sub-category-link::attr(href)').extract()
        if urls:
            for url in urls:
                yield scrapy.Request(url=self.base_url + url, callback=self.parse_brand)

    def parse_brand(self, response):
        self.log("parse_brand: I just visited: "+ response.url)
        for d in set(response.css('div.product-tile::attr(data-tcproduct)').extract()):
            d = json.loads(d)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=d['product_url_page'].replace("p","P"), callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.log("parse: I just visited: " + response.url)
        links = response.css('link').extract()
        product_id = 'P618001'
        # product_id = re.findall(r'P[0-9]*', [x for x in links if 'sephora.fr' in x][0])[0]
        self.params['filter.q0'] = 'id:eq:' + product_id
        self.params['filter.q1'][0] = 'productid :eq:' + product_id
        self.params['filter.q2'][1] = 'productid :eq:' + product_id
        perfume = requests.get("https://api.bazaarvoice.com/data/batch.json", params=self.params)
        print("perfume.json(): ", perfume.json())
```

Comment: Looks like a banned IP. Works fine for me  (but with a lot of filtered duplicate requests).

Comment: Ew, so my IP might be banned? It seems that I can still visit the website ...

Comment: Try to use VPN and run your code.

Comment: @gangabass It works... Do you think my original URL is banned forever?

Comment: How should I know? You can contact site owner.

Comment: @gangabass I don't know? I was just asking ... Ok, I will :)